# Saving if statement into an array for inserting into database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following section of if statements that creates the respective code dependent on what option the user has selected from the view.

How could I save the selected options if statement so that I could insert it into the db.

I have tried `'field'   =>  ''.$_REQUEST['add_fields_type'].''` but of course it just shows the selected option and not the html it should produce

**Code:**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['add_fields_type']))
            {
                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'input')
                {
                    //$fieldLabel;
                    form_input($formData, TRUE);


                }

                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'textarea')
                {
                    $fieldLabel;
                    form_textarea($formData, TRUE);
                }

                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'radiobutton')
                {
                    $fieldLabel;
                    form_radio($formData, TRUE);
                }

                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'checkbox')
                {
                    $fieldLabel;
                    form_checkbox($formData, TRUE);
                }
```

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, you want to save the resulting HTML into the database right?

Comment: @UzairSajid yep I need to get what the form_ would produce and put this into the 'field' => '' array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'textarea') {
    $fieldLabel;
    form_textarea($formData, TRUE);
}
```

You should do this if you want to save the HTML:

```
if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'textarea') {
    $fieldLabel;
    $fields[] = form_textarea($formData, TRUE);
}
```

Or if you want to save the field data with field type, then do this:

```
if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'textarea') {
    $fieldLabel;
    $fields[ $_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] ] = form_textarea($formData, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: this sounds better, op will just later need to serialize the array and insert it into the database and when he needs to output he will just unserialize the array and output the values. if you can put add the code for that in your answer, it is going to help him a lot.